# How to exclude some elements from XSL output indent?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I need to transform an xml doc and I want the output to be formatted so I use `<xsl:output indent="yes" />`. But I want a specific element to not indent. For example, my xml (after any transformation, like removing elements etc) is unformatted like this:

```
<root><code><run><formula>xyz</formula></code></root>
```

with `<xsl:output indent="yes" />` I getting output like this:

```
<root>
<code>
<run>
<formula>xyz</formula>
</run>
</code>
</root>
```

I am looking for output like this:

```
<root>
<code>
<run><formula>xyz</formula></run>
</code>
</root>
```

basically I don't want `<run>` (and elements inside it) to format.

Can this be done with XSL? Or I need to parse the file, after XSL transformation, to remove \n after `<run>` and before `</run>` ?

(note: my xml is big with hundreds of elements. The above is just an example)
(note 2: I am using java. Thus the java tag)

Comment: The real question is: _Why do you want to do that?_ Formatting (such as indenting) is for humans only. The XML is valid and well-formed without any line breaks and/or indenting.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Formatting helps with source control diff. In my case the "run" element needs to stay intact for other reasons (legacy system that cannot import the file if the run element is formatted)

Comment: XSLT 3 (as supported for Java with Saxon 9.8 and later) allows you to declare elements to be exempted from indentation with the `suppress-indentation` attribute e.g. `<xsl:output indent="yes" suppress-indentation="run"/>`. Example is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQg9/1 using Saxon 9.8.

Comment: Spec section is https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#serialization.

Answer (score 3):

XSLT 3.0 allows you to say `<xsl:output indent="yes" suppress-indentation="run"/>`. For this you will need to switch to an XSLT 3.0 processor, which in the Java world means Saxon.